How to adapt a callable Iterator for range-based for loop without pre-reading the next element
I am having a callable iterator, i.e. an std::function<std::optional<T>()> instance that is called repeatedly until it returns std::nullopt. It's easy to collect all returned values into an std::vector, but I am looking for some sort of adapter to use it in a (pure) for-loop:
https://godbolt.org/z/M3G3qdP39
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <vector>

std::function<std::optional<int>()> callableIterator() {
    return [value = 0]() mutable -> std::optional<int> {
        if (value == 10) {
            return {};
        }
        return value++;
    };
}

template <typename It>
auto collectCallable(It&& it) {
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(*it())>;
    std::vector<T> result;
    while (auto e = it()) {
        result.push_back(std::move(*e));
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename It>
struct CallableIterable {
    It it;
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(*it())>;

    CallableIterable(It&& it) : it(std::move(it)) {}

    struct EndIterator {};

    struct Iterator {
        CallableIterable& iterable;
        std::optional<T> valueHolder;

        Iterator(CallableIterable& iterable) : iterable(iterable), valueHolder(iterable.it()) {}

        Iterator& operator++() { 
            valueHolder = iterable.it();
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator!=(EndIterator) { return !!valueHolder;}

        T operator*() { return *valueHolder; }

    };

    Iterator begin() {
        return {*this};
    }

    EndIterator end() {
        return {};
    }
};

int main() {
    for (auto value : collectCallable(callableIterator())) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
    for (auto value : CallableIterable(callableIterator())) {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

To determine whether the iterator is exhausted, I need to always read an element ahead in CallableIterable::Iterator++(). Is there a for-based solution that does not require this?

what do you mean by a pure for-loop and for-based solution ? care to type out your expected syntax ?

do you target a specific c++ version ?

It is not so hard with a while loop like this : std::optional<int> value; while((value = function()) != std::nullopt) (no boiler plate needed)

Not sure if it fully answers the question but here is a solution that relies on coroutines (and so on c++20):
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <generator>  // https://github.com/lewissbaker/generator

std::function<std::optional<int>()> callableIterator() {
    return [value = 0]() mutable -> std::optional<int> {
        if (value == 10) {
            return {};
        }
        return value++;
    };
}

template <typename It>
auto generator (It&& it) -> std::generator<std::decay_t<decltype(*it())>>
{
    while (auto e = it())  { co_yield *e; }
}

int main() 
{
    for (auto value : generator(callableIterator())) 
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Actually, it mimics your collectCallable without having to create a container whose only usage is to be iterated in a for-range loop.
Note however the usage of the generator class that is not available in c++20 (and so use a pre-version) but seems to be there in c++23.
Demo
